# Triage question was already closed!

Tags: discussion

So I am reviewing Triage questions on my Friday evening at midnight ... and one of the questions was obviously (to me) off topic - in fact I thought it was an obvious test to make sure I was paying attention.

It's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406298/which-design-pattern-is-used-for-cell-rendering-in-swing and the Triage Review link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8170687)

But when I chose to close it as 'Unsalvageable' thinking it was *Off topic* it turns out it was already closed...

Is that normal? Shouldn't questions be taken out of the review queue as soon as they are closed?

Comment: How many seconds did it take you to decide it should be closed and to close it after the review loaded? That's how large a window of opportunity there was for someone to finish dupehammering it into oblivion from a review page they had already loaded. Triage does not lock reviews.